# Constructing ROC curve for FAR and FRR values

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm, libsvm, roc

I have a one-vs-all classifier set. This set consists of, let's say, 3 classifiers (LibSVM SVMs) each trained on data for a class and all other class data. The current setup for a sample is that the classifier of the 3 classes that gives the highest score is said to be the matching class.

This setup gives a FAR and FRR result. The issue is that the FAR and FRR results are not enough to construct an ROC curve, which I need. I am wondering what I can do to produce and ROC curve.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using "multiclass ROC curves" (see e.g. [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/2155/112731) for more details). Usually, you either look at *each class* individually, or even at *each pair of classes* individually. I'll provide a short `R` example of how the first one could look, which is less complicated and still gives a good feeling for how well individual classes could be recognized.

You first need to obtain some class probabilities (for reproducibility, this is what you already have):

```
# Computing some class probabilities for a 3 class problem using repeated cross validation
library(caret)
model <- train(x = iris[,1:2], y = iris[,5], method = 'svmLinear', trControl = trainControl(method = 'repeatedcv', number = 10, repeats = 10, classProbs = T, savePredictions = T))

# those are the class probabilities for each sample
> model$pred
pred        obs     setosa  versicolor   virginica rowIndex C     Resample
[...]
11  virginica virginica 1.202911e-02 0.411723759 0.57624713      116 1 Fold01.Rep01
12 versicolor virginica 4.970032e-02 0.692146087 0.25815359      122 1 Fold01.Rep01
13  virginica virginica 5.258769e-03 0.310586094 0.68415514      125 1 Fold01.Rep01
14  virginica virginica 4.321882e-05 0.202372698 0.79758408      131 1 Fold01.Rep01
15 versicolor virginica 1.057353e-03 0.559993337 0.43894931      147 1 Fold01.Rep01
[...]
```

Now you can look at the ROC curve for each class individually. For each curve, the `FRR` indicates the rate how often samples of this class were predicted as samples of *some other class*, while the `FAR` indicates the rate how often a sample of *some other class* was predicted as a sample of this class:

```
plot(roc(predictor = model$pred$setosa, response = model$pred$obs=='setosa'), xlab = 'FAR', ylab = '1-FRR')
plot(roc(predictor = model$pred$versicolor, response = model$pred$obs=='versicolor'), add=T, col=2)
plot(roc(predictor = model$pred$virginica, response = model$pred$obs=='virginica'), add=T, col=3)
legend('bottomright', legend = c('setosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica'), col=1:3, lty=1)
```

[image: Multiclass ROC]

As mentioned before, you could instead also look at the ROC curve for *each pair of classes*, but IMHO this transports much more information, hence it is more complicated/takes longer to grasp the contained information.